# How to use .env files in laravel + vuejs project?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, development-environment, production-environment

> I have laravel(5.8) + vuejs(2.6.10) project in single repo.

Currently, i am using `env` variables for frontend(vuejs) from `.env` of laravel using prefix `MIX`.

*context:*
https://medium.com/@weehong/laravel-5-7-vue-vue-router-spa-5e07fd591981

**But**

I need separate `.env` files for vuejs other than `.env` of laravel. is it possible? how?

I need make build according to .env files(while not not using Vue-cli)

Comment: Make your own env.js file and and decalre your all variable in that file and import it in app.js file

Comment: why don't you just create a new config file and set it via extra `.env` values. I'd create lines in my default `.env` file like `VUE_SOME_VALUE` or `FRONTEND_SOME_VALUE`

Comment: visit https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes link.

Comment: @KaranSadana i'm not want to declare variables as config, need to declare in `.env`. so we can make build according to `.env` files.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya it's useful while project created using vue-cli. i have combine larave_ vuejs project setup and used laravel mixin

Answer (score 2):

Laravel already provides this functionality out of the box. For any variables you want exposed to `laravel/mix`, you just prefix them with `MIX_`

`MIX_HOST=https://example.com`

And you can now access it within your Vue application as `process.env.MIX_HOST`.

Mix will not include any other variables from your `.env` file if they're not prefixed with `MIX_`.

For a more controlled approach, you can use `dotenv` for this and specify the filename of your `.env` file you wish to load in your `Vue` application:

```
yarn add -D dotnev // npm i dotenv -D
```

Then in your main js file for your Vue app:

```
require('dotenv').config({
  path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env-vue')
})
```

This will pollute the `process.env` global with any values in this file.